# Custom protocols

Tags: swift, swift3, anonymous-function, swift-protocols

Im getting this error "Class declaration cannot close over value 'viewcontainer' defined in outer scope"

I created a procotol called **NetworkResponse** which have two methods on sucessResponse and onErrorResponse.

Then I have a class called **Callback** that extends from **NetworkResponse** and forced to implement that methods.

Here is my function :

```
 public func login (callback : Callback, viewController : UIViewController) {



        let callbackInstance: NetworkResponse = {

            class callback : Callback {



                override func onSucessResponse(response : NSDictionary){

                    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
                override func onErrorResponse(message : String, code : Int){
                    print("error")
                }
            }

            return callback()
        }()

        postPath(callback: callbackInstance as? Callback)

}
```

I want to dismiss the controller from the anonymous class.

Any recomendation ?

Comment: Any chance you're a Java developer?

Comment: Yes I'm. New guy in swift

Comment: I think you should use `closure` instead of `protocol` to define `onSuccess`, and `onError` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to define a protocol and Callback class. Closure is just what you need.

```
import UIKit

public class TestInnerClass: UIViewController {

    public func login(successCallback: ((response: NSDictionary) -> Void), errorCallback: ((message: String, code: Int) -> Void)) {

        let success = false
        let response = NSDictionary()

        //
        // Make your login request here, and change the `success` value depends on your response
        // let response = ...
        //
        // If you are making a async request to login, then put the following codes inside your request callback closure.
        //

        if success {
            successCallback(response: response)
        } else {
            errorCallback(message: "error occurred", code: -1)
        }
    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        login({
                (response) in
                // Get Called when success
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }, errorCallback: ({
                // Get called when failed
                (message, code) in
                print(message)
            }))
    }
}
```

I have written some [sample codes](https://github.com/enix223/SwiftPlayground/blob/master/SwiftPlayground/TestInnerClass.swift) for your case in my Github repo, and this example is using Alamofire to make network request, Just for your reference.

PS: Since I still using Xcode 7.3.1, so you may need to do some changes to the above code to adopt the swift 3 syntax requirement.